# How to display DB results in listview Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, arraylist

I am having a hard time getting items in a column of a particular table in my `SQLite db` to be stored in an `ArrayList` and then attached to a `ListView` on my app.

Any comprehensive and detailed example on how to do this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following code

```
final ListView veh_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    String query = "SELECT rowid _id,name,imei FROM vehicles WHERE group_='UN-GROUPED'";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query,null);
    List<String> veh_s = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cursor.getCount()>0){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            veh_s.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.checkable_item, R.id.veh_name, veh_s);
        veh_list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Vehicles", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Create a layout which will be used as `ListView's` row

**R.layout.checkable_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
     android:text="TEST"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
     android:padding="15dp"
     android:id="@+id/veh_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have 4 components. Two xml layouts, a cursor adapter (creating an array from the cursor isn't necessary) and the code to retrieve the data from the database. The first layout includes the ListView, the second is the layout for each entry/row.

The **first Layout** as would be invoked via setContentView in the onCreate method of the activity. This would inlcude something along the lines of :-

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/aslbclv01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_listview_height"
    android:longClickable="true">
</ListView>
```

*Note as I understand the height must be specific for the ListView to scroll.*

An example of the **second layout** entry/row xml follows (**R.layout.activity_shop_list_entry** in this example):-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorlistviewroweven"
    tools:context=".ShopListEntryActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_name_entry"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/standard_subsubsubheading_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_city_entry"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/standard_subsubsubheading_text_size"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_street_entry"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/standard_subsubsubheading_text_size"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The **Cursor adapter** (Custom in this case, as I've never used the Simple Cursor Adapter) for the above is :-

```
package mjt.shopper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Mike092015 on 2/02/2016.
 */
class ShopsCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public ShopsCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertview, parent);
        Context context = view.getContext();
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorlistviewroweven));
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorlistviewrowodd));
        }
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_shop_list_entry, parent, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view,Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView textViewShopName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_name_entry);
        TextView textViewShopStreet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_street_entry);
        TextView textViewShopCity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_city_entry);

        textViewShopName.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.SHOPS_COLUMN_NAME_INDEX));
        textViewShopStreet.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.SHOPS_COLUMN_STREET_INDEX));
        textViewShopCity.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.SHOPS_COLUMN_CITY_INDEX));
    }
}
```

Note that SHOPS.COLUMN_????_INDEX is the offset of the respective column within the cursor.

*Also note that getView isn't required (in the above it sets the rows to alternate colours).*

**R.layout.activity_shop_list_entry** is the second xml which has the TextViews that are set.

Within the activity, in the onCreate method, the following code populates the ListView :-

```
        final Cursor csr = shopperdb.getShopsAsCursor();
        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.aslbclv01);
        final ShopsCursorAdapter adapter = new ShopsCursorAdapter(this,csr, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The first line extracts the data as a cursor from the database via the getShopsAsCursor method.
The second line gets the ListView's id.
The third line instantiates the CursorAdapter (ShopsCursorAdapter in this case).
The fourthline sets the ListView's cursoradapter.

As per comment here's the **getShopsAsCursor** method, which is coded within the DBHelper :-

```
public Cursor getShopsAsCursor() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM " + SHOPS_TABLE_NAME +
            " ORDER BY " + SHOPS_COLUMN_NAME + ", " + SHOPS_COLUMN_CITY + ";";
    return db.rawQuery(sqlstr,null);
}
```

Comment: The main difference between this answer and the other answer (starts with _Refer the following code_) is that the other answer creates an array and uses an array adapter as opposed to a cursor adapter. There are pros and cons for each. For example you need the additional code and loop to create the array. However, you can close the cursor once you have created the array.

Comment: Hello Mike, please kindly show the getShopsAsCursor() method

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cursor adapter to directly set data from SQLite to listview.
here is the sample code.

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {       

        TextView nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
        nameView.setText(name);
    }
}
```

for more info https://coderwall.com/p/fmavhg/android-cursoradapter-with-custom-layout-and-how-to-use-it

Answer (score 0):

**try to below code**

**ListViewActivity.java**

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity
{
    ListView listCustom;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    ProductDatabase customerDB;
    ProductAdapter customAdapter;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
    public static String DB_PATH; 
    private ArrayList<LevelList> results = new ArrayList<LevelList>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.product_list);

        levelLists = new ArrayList<LevelList>();
        customerDB = new ProductDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        customerDB = customerDB.open();
        listCustom = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mainMenu();
    }

    public void mainMenu()
    {
        results.clear();
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.gt.invoicemaker/databases/";
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);  
          final Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT  ID AS _id, USERID, INAME, IPRICE FROM ITEM, null);
          // Note: Master is the one table in External db. Here we trying to access the records of table from external db. 
         if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        LevelList results1 = new LevelList();
                        int _id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                        String userName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("INAME"));

                        results1.id = _id;
                        results1.item = userName;
                        results.add(results1);
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                }
         }
                customAdapter = new ProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(), results);
                listCustom.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
  }
}
```

**ProductAdapter.java**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<LevelList> listItem;

      public ProductAdapter(Context c,List<LevelList> listItem) {
          mContext = c;
          this.listItem = listItem;
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return listItem.size();
      }

      @Override
      public Object getItem(int position) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return listItem;
      }

      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return position;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
              .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

          View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleproduct, null,true);

              TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.single_product);
              textView.setText(listItem.get(position).item);
          return rowView;
      }
}
```

**product_list.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/addnew"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/mainview"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:scrollbars="none" >

                </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**singleproduct.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/single_product"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```